# RESTEasy JSON Exception Response: Send list of objects

Tags: java, json, web-services, exception, resteasy

I have web client (HTML5) and backend server based on RESTEasy webservices and session beans. In my server side code I am iterating over list of objects and per object i am executing some business logic:

```
List<TestTO> failedTestList = new ArrayList<TestTO>();
for (TestTO testTO : testTOList) {
    try {
        // some weired business logic :P
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable to create data -" + e.getMessage());
        failedTestList.add(testTO);
    }
}

if (!failedTestList.isEmpty()) {
   // throw custom exception embedded with failed TO list 
}
```

I have written custome exception handlers, to catch exceptions and return proper response back to client. This class looks like:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<CustomException> {

    public CustomException getCustomErrorCode(final CustomException customException) {

        // Some logic to get cause and set error code
        return customException;
    }


    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final CustomException customException) {

        return Response.serverError().entity(
                "{\"Error Code\":\"" + getCustomErrorCode(customException).getErrorCode() + "\", "
                        + "\"Error Message\":\"" + customException.getLocalizedMessage() + "\"}").build();
    }
}
```

I am thinking of an option to send this failed TO list back to client, so that it can understand processing of which objects got failed. I was going through different articles, but could not find anything which fits my requirement.

Please give me an idea and link to reference, on how to implement such requirement. Please note that, my client expects response in JSON format. Please let me know, if you require more information.
Thanks.

Comment: what is your main problem here? do you want to parse the json error message to your client(HTML5)?

Comment: What i need is a way to send failed object list back to client. I can not embedd this list in my CustomException and return object type might vary depending on which method is called. I need to throw exception so that client knows something has failed. Along with that in some cases I need to send back failed object list. I was not able to think of any option on how to do it, in case of HTML5 client expecting JSON response.